# My app works but log gives "No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff."

Tags: android

I have an app that works fine on my emulators and on my own device. However, when I navigate between views I get the message

```
No package ID ff found for ID 0xffffffff.
```

all the time. I do not know what it means or where it comes from.

Searching through the log I also find these messages:

```
I/low.wordscanne: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-10 16:25:10.984 26226-26226/? I/chatty:uid=10099(com.myapp.erikbylow.wordscanner) identical 2 lines
2019-04-10 16:25:10.985 26226-26226/? I/low.wordscanne: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-04-10 16:25:10.992 26226-26226/? W/low.wordscanne: Unsupported class loader
```

and in `MainActivity - onCreate` I always get this warning

```
Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-10 16:26:24.328 26226-26226/com.myapp.myname.wordscanner W/low.wordscanne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-10 16:26:24.328 26226-26226/com.myapp.myname.wordscanner W/low.wordscanne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-10 16:26:24.328 26226-26226/com.myapp.myname.wordscanner W/low.wordscanne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-10 16:26:24.328 26226-26226/com.myapp.myname.wordscanner W/low.wordscanne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-10 16:26:24.328 26226-26226/com.myapp.myname.wordscanner W/low.wordscanne: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
```

The app works at least on my devices, have anyone experienced something similar?

I do use an `aar-module` imported from another project. Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It happened to me too,
I've struggled for a few hours now for why it happens.
Seems like changing from:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

to:

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
```

solved the case.
Tell me if it happened to you too (probably a bug in the update)

Comment: As @El_Loco said, It seems a bug with `alpha4` version. Also worked when I downgraded to `alpha3`.

Comment: And it has returned back on `2.0.0-alpha5`!

Comment: Also on `2.0.0-beta1`

Comment: It seems that still present on 2.0.0-beta2

Comment: @Luis I suggest not to use 2.0.0-beta2. It has some issues, such as this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135828276

Comment: confirm still on 2.0.0-beta2 and still has some bugs

Comment: Can confirm it's in 2.0.2

Comment: Can't use MotionLayout with NestedScrollView because of this error, uh I hate Android..

Comment: Can confirm it's still on 2.1.2

Comment: still present in 2.1.3, see also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132651809

Comment: turns out I was trying to call a @ ColorInt when I was supposed to be calling a @ ColorRes - so I think I have a different issue

Answer (score 2):

This error **may** be caused by a bug in Android Studio and/or Android Gradle Plugin. In my case, it probably was. As a user of Android Studio Preview (Iguana 2023.2.1 Canary 11), I shouldn't really be surprised.

After performing the **sacred purification ritual**, the error was gone:

- **File** > **Invalidate Caches…** > **Invalidate and Restart**
- **Build** > **Rebuild Project**

Comment: I have also remove my ```ConstraintLayout``` Dependency then restarted and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case that problem hit me in my Xamarin Forms after upgraded to the last version of many Google AndroidX Nuget Packages. I downgraded to the previous version one by one and the culprit was in the **Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4**. The **v1.0.0.6** was the last one that worked without problems for me. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out I was trying to call a @ColorInt when I was supposed to be calling a @ColorRes.