# No package ID <?> found for ID <?>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, samsung-mobile

When ever i try to run my android application on Samsung M31 (android version 11) i keep getting this error which causes issue with touch.

how can i resolve this issue?

there is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615291/my-app-works-but-log-gives-no-package-id-ff-found-for-id-0xffffffff) but that solution doesn't seem to work.

```
2022-01-23 19:21:52.975 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.975 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 85 found for ID 0x85eafab5.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.975 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID ae found for ID 0xaedaae96.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.976 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 34 found for ID 0x3454c9e6.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.976 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.977 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 6b found for ID 0x6b1fd282.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.977 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.978 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 85 found for ID 0x85eafab5.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.978 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.978 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID ca found for ID 0xcafbb734.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.979 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 85 found for ID 0x85eafab5.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.979 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.979 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 85 found for ID 0x85eafab5.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.979 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.980 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID 75 found for ID 0x7556752c.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.980 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID ae found for ID 0xaedaae96.
2022-01-23 19:21:52.980 31840-31840/com.abc.def E/com.bc.ef: No package ID cd found for ID 0xcd0291a0.
```